# a generator returning the output of a coroutine pipeline

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

I'm trying to decompose a larger function (like searching a trie) into generators with nested coroutines. The generator receives values, sends them to the coroutines, and yields the final output, if any.

```
def filter_pipe(func, target):
    while True:
        node = (yield)
        term = (yield)
        node = func(node, term)
        if node:
            target.send(node)

def and_in_the_end():
    while True:
        node = (yield)
        yield node
        yield node
```

Every coroutine has an expression, which is the conditional basis for sending to target.

`source(node, term)` returns the updated value when isolated.

```
def source(node, term):
    sink = and_in_the_end()
    sink.__next__()

    funcs = [good_node, naughty_node]

    for func in funcs:
        target = filter_pipe(func, sink)
        target.__next__()

        target.send(node)
        target.send(term)

    result = sink.__next__()
    return result

print(source('node', 'node')) --> 'node was good'
print(source('node', 'other')) --> 'node was naughty'
```

After nesting inside a generator `branch(funcs)`:

```
def branch(funcs):
    while True:
        node = (yield)
        term = (yield)

        def source(node, term):
            # funcs = [good_node, naughty_node] <-- removed
            ...

        yield source(node, term)

x = branch([good_node, naughty_node])
x.__next__()    
x.send('node')
x.send('term')

y = x.__next__()
print(y) --> 'None'
```

Just writing the code to print from branch gave me bad vibes, but where is it getting None from? Is this generally a bad way to use generators?

Comment: It's hard to say what you are trying to achieve. Could you please, describe what would be the expected flow and behavior?